# Barra de progresso c# (windows form) usando dados do mysql

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Atualmente tenho esse código em um dos forms de uma aplicação em desenvolvimento e gostaria de criar uma barra de progresso que ao clicar no botao Ver (que demora um pouco para preencher o datagrid) mostraria o progresso dos dados.

```
namespace Odin
{
    public partial class frmBuscaPorNome : Form
    {
        public frmBuscaPorNome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Conexao bd = new Conexao();

        private void CarregarGrid()
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM ebt_iw ORDER BY id;";
            dtgBusca.DataSource = bd.ExecutarConsultas(sql);
        }

        private void btnBusca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Busca = txtBusca.Text;
            string bsc = "SELECT * FROM ebt_iw WHERE nome LIKE '" + Busca + "%' ;";
            dtgBusca.DataSource = bd.ExecutarConsultas(bsc);

        }

        private void btnVer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CarregarGrid();
        }

        private void btnSair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
```

Essa é a classe de conexao:

```
 class Conexao
    {
        MySqlConnection conexao;

        public void Conectar()
        {
            string string_conexao = "Persist Security Info = false;server = localhost;database = ebtiw;uid = root;pwd = ;SslMode=none;";
            conexao = new MySqlConnection(string_conexao);
            conexao.Open();
        }

        public void ExecutarComandos(string sql)
        {
            Conectar();
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexao);
            comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conexao.Close();
        }

        public DataTable ExecutarConsultas(string query)
        {
            Conectar();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter dados = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conexao);
            dados.Fill(dt);
            conexao.Close();

            return dt; //dt armazena os resultado obtido de execuçao do SELECT ( da string query)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Definindo diretamente o `DataSource` não consegue ter o comportamento que pretende. Se adicionar linha a linha, aí sim, já conseguiria, mas perdia performance...

Comment: voce indica um outro jeito de fazer isso? tipo exibir uma caixa de texto escrito 'carregando' ate a tabela carregar ?

Comment: Não, ir adicionando linha a linha à grelha dentro de um ciclo e ao mesmo tempo incrementando o valor da `ProgressBar`.

Comment: tem algum evento ou propiedade que consigo saber quando a tabela carrega totalmente?

Comment: Sim, pelo evento da grelha `DataBindingComplete` (se for uma `DataGridView`).

Comment: Amigo muito obrigado, me ajudou demais